# Objective C pow function mixed precision result

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, precision, pow, libm

General question on the pow function in objective-c.

Why does the following code spit out 
ans=4.9999999 when the base = 125

```
NSDecimalNumber * base = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc ]initWithString:@"125"];
NSDecimalNumber * root = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"3"];
double ans=pow(125, 1.0/[root doubleValue]);
```

and exactly 3 when base = 27

```
NSDecimalNumber * base = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc ]initWithString:@"27"];
NSDecimalNumber * root = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"3"];
double ans=pow(125, 1.0/[root doubleValue]);
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be `double ans = pow([base doubleValue], 1.0/[root doubleValue]);`? Neither of your calculations is using 27.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few factors at work here.  Most importantly, `1.0/3.0` is not exactly one-third, so you are **not** computing the cube root of `base`.  Instead, the computation that you have specified is:

```
base**0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
```

or

```
exp(0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 * log(base))
```

When `base` is `125`, the exact real-number result of this computation is:

```
4.999999999999999553291243227753830961690873860134487744...
```

The two closest representable doubles to this value are `5.0` and:

```
4.99999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

The latter value is just barely closer to the mathematically exact result, so the `pow` function has returned the best possible (or "correctly rounded") answer.

When you do the same computation with `base` equal to 27, the mathematically exact real-number result is:

```
2.99999999999999981704430129767885583952101310176125736...
```

In this case, this number is somewhat closer to `3.0` than it is to any other representable double, so again `pow` has returned the best possible result.

So in these cases, the `pow` function is giving you the most accurate possible results to the computations you have prompted it with.  Now, that said, there is no guarantee that `pow` does so for all possible inputs (and indeed, in general it doesn't).  You won't get such accurate results for all inputs, and you will get *significantly* less accurate results for many inputs on some platforms.  In general, you should not depend on last-bit rounding of the `pow` function, or of any function that is not explicitly defined to produce correctly-rounded results.

In short: the results you got are the best possible results, and on some other platforms you won't be so lucky.

---

Alternatives:

- You might consider using the `cbrt` function, which also does not guarantee correct rounding, but at least is computing the cube root and not the 0.3333333333333333148296...th power.
- If you know *a priori* that the result should be an integer, you might round it to the closest integer via the `round` or `rint` function.
- If you really require exact last bit rounding, consider using the CRLibm library.  This will come with some performance cost, but if you absolutely must have correct rounding, it is the only good option (but note that it will produce exactly the same results for these particular examples).

Comment: Of the alternatives mentioned, ended up going with the cbrt function.